# OpenGL3 Rotate object around itself center

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

Ill try to rotate object in openGL (using OpenTK framework), but he rotate around zero point. Its logicly that object rotating around center, but i dont known how shoud hes rotating aroud itself center (or other point)

```cs
    public static void Texture(Region region, float x, float y, float z, float rotateX, float rotateY, float rotateZ)
        => Texture(
            region,
            Matrix4.CreateTranslation(x, y, z),
            Matrix4.CreateRotationX(rotateX) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(rotateY) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(rotateZ),
            TestGame.Camera.GetViewMatrix(),
            TestGame.Camera.GetProjectionMatrix()
            );
    public static void Texture(Region region, Matrix4 translate, Matrix4 model, Matrix4 view, Matrix4 projection)
    {
        Shaders.TextureShader.Texture(TextureUnit.Texture0); //Bind texture as 0 in shader
        region.Reference.Use(); //Bind texture as 0

        Shaders.TextureShader.Matrix4("translate", translate);
        Shaders.TextureShader.Matrix4("model", model);
        Shaders.TextureShader.Matrix4("view", view);
        Shaders.TextureShader.Matrix4("projection", projection);
        Shaders.TextureShader.Draw();
    }
```

```c
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 translate;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main(void)
{
    texCoord = aTexCoord;

    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1) * translate * model * view * projection;
}
```

Comment: Are you using raw main order matrices? Typically, OpenGL matrices are stored with column major order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplications are not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), the order mattes. Rotate the object before translating it:

<s>`gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1) * translate * model * view * projection;`</s>

```c
gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1) * model * translate * view * projection;
```

Comment: Yes, its works, thnks!

Comment: And another one question, can i control rotation behavior in code?